# load an external page with ckeditor into a div

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, ckeditor, external

Here is the code for my external page with ckeditor (in.php)

```
<html>   
<head>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>   
<body>       
<textarea name=ck ></textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'ck' );
</script>
</body> </html>
```

Here is the code for the page I'm trying to load this page into (out.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready( function () { $('#page').load('in.php');

});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id=page ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Loading the out.php nothing shows up and the in IE object expected error.
The in.php on the other hand works fine standalone.

Can anyone suggest any solution? I've tried `getScript`, putting functions in it and putting code back and forth on the 2 pages, nothing works. I would also be interest if anyone can help with a Prototype solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using jQuery, so don't forget to include the jQuery library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```